# Java 8 Lambda for Anonymous Class

Tags: java, lambda, anonymous-class

I have a tricky situation here, which I would like to optimize from the code perspective. Is there any way to shorten the following method via Lambda / Java8 expressions?

```
// total amount of audiences
registry.register("metric.persons.total", new CachedGauge<Integer>(1,TimeUnit.MINUTES) {
    @Override
    protected Integer loadValue() {
        return personService.findAll().size();
    }
});
```

The CachedGauge class is looking like this:

```
public abstract class CachedGauge<T> implements Gauge<T> {
    protected CachedGauge(long timeout, TimeUnit timeoutUnit) {
        ...
    }

    protected abstract T loadValue();
        ...
    }
}
```

Would be really great to see if there is a way, the tricky part here is that there is a default constructor and the class is parameterized.

best, fri

Comment: Does `personService` come from the anonymous class's containing scope, or is it a public/protected field inherited from `CachedGauge`?

Comment: ah sorry... the person service is a protected field in the outer class, similar to the "registry" object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
registry.register("metric.persons.total", 
    CachedGauge.of(1,TimeUnit.MINUTES, ()->personService.findAll().size() ) 
);
```

And I think you can figure out how to implement `CachedGauge.of(long, TimeUnit, Supplier<T>)`

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. Problem is, that the CachedGauge is 3rd party class, which I tried not to override... But I then create my own Utils class...

Comment: @Fritz - exactly. It's a util method that can be put anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completion of this thread, my Utils class looks like this

```
public class MetricUtils {

    public static <T> CachedGauge<T> cachedGauge(long timeout, TimeUnit timeoutUnit, Supplier<T> supplier) {
        return new CachedGauge<T>(timeout, timeoutUnit) {
            @Override
            protected T loadValue() {
                return supplier.get();
            }
        };
    }
}
```